# Get JSON response from Firestore for subcollections

Tags: json, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to combine the information for all the doctors:

`{"id": "...", "firstName": "...", "lastName": "..."}`

---

My Firestore data tree looks like:

[image]

I am writing my `GET` as:

```
app.get('/doctors/cardiology/doctors', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const doctorsDetailsQuerySnapshot = await db.collection("doctors").doc("cardiology").listCollections();
    const doctors: any[] = [];
    doctorsDetailsQuerySnapshot.forEach((doc1) => {
      doctors.push({
        id: doc1.id,
        data: doc1.doc(doc1.id).collection(doc1.id),
      });
    });
    res.status(200).json(doctors);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
```

Actual output:

```
[
    {
        "id": "919505294523",
        "data": {
            .... metadata....
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "919505294525",
        "data": {
            .... metadata....
        }
    }
]
```

Expected output:

```
[
  {
      "id": "919505294523",
      "data": {
          "id": "919505294523",
          "firstName": "B.F.",
          "lastName": "Skinner"
      }
  },
  {
      "id": "919505294525",
      "data": {
          "id": "919505294525",
          "firstName": "Carl",
          "lastName": "Rogers"
      }
  }
]
```

Could somebody please help my novice mind? Almost stuck for 2 hours.

Comment: From your database structure, I understand that you have a collections of doctors under `cardiology` document and then under this collection you keep a document for each `doctor`. Could you elaborate on your database structure and why you do this?

Comment: @tzovourn: I created such schema, because everytime I fetch information about doctor, I must be knowing which speciality that doctor belongs to.
So, such schema will help me categorize doctors under scehma.

I am sure, there should be improvement.
Please share your thought.
BTW, the issue is question is resolved.

Comment: please check my answer regarding your question about the database structure. Also please consider sharing the solution to your issue as an answer, in order to help members of the community that may encounter the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

As an answer to your question about the database structure.

Right now your structure is like this:

```
\collection(doctors)
   \document(specialization)
      \collection(doctorId)
         \document(doctorID)
```

So you have a collection of `doctors` that contains a document for each specialization(eg `cardiology`) and under each specialization you have a collection per doctor, which contains a document with the doctor fields.

Instead I would suggest a simpler and more straightforward structure such the following:

```
\collection(Doctors)
  \document(doctorID)
```

My suggestion is to make a collection of `Doctors` which will contain a document for each doctor. In the fields of the document, you may include the already existing fields(firstName, id, lastName) and add one more field, `specialization` (eg "specialization: cardiology").

This is a much simpler implementation and you can still query the doctors based on their specialization using the `where('specialization', '==', 'cardiology')`. More information on the `where()` method may be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries)